# Android: Cannot resolve getViewById()

Tags: android

This is the function that needs to get findViewById of an AutoCompleteTextView defined in another xml file with id = suggestionsTextView

```
private void updateCandidates() {
    if (!mCompletionOn) {
        if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            //  list.add(mComposing.toString());
            String asd = mComposing.toString();
            asd = asd.trim();


            DBManager db;
            db=new DBManager(getApplicationContext());
            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.suggest(asd);

            AutoCompleteTextView t = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.suggestionsTextView);



            if(c!=null)
            {
                if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                    String text1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("word"));
                    str.append(text1).append("\n");
                    String text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("gremeaning"));
                    String arr[] = text.split(";");
                    for (String a : arr) {
                        a = a.trim();
                        System.out.println(a);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is the word = " + a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        list.add(a);
                        str.append(a).append("\n");


                    }

                    t.setText(str);
                }


                }c.close();



        }
    }
}
```

The error i'm getting is can't resolve findViewById. No fixes available. Please help.

Comment: Where is your 'updateCandidates' method? In the Activity? Are you using Fragments at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void updateCandidates(Activity context) {

}
```

you need the get the context of activity in this function then you have to called like as follow

```
context.findViewById(Some ID Here)
```

Comment: That fixed this particular problem. But, this function updateCandidates() has been called multiple times. What parameter do I pass?

Comment: Create static class as follow

public class Utils {   public static Activity context;}

and then add following line in you MainActivity onCreate Method

Utils.context=this;

now call  findViewById as Follow

Utils.context.findViewById(Some ID Here)